# How to write on HDFS using pyarrow

Tags: hdfs, pyarrow, libhdfs

I'm using python with pyarrow library and I'd like to write a pandas dataframe on HDFS. Here is the code I have

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

fs = pa.hdfs.connect(namenode, port, username, kerb_ticket)
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

According to the documentation I should use the following code to write a pyarrow.Table on HDFS

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
pq.write_parquet(table, 'filename.parquet')
```

What I don't understand is where should I use my connection (`fs`), because if I don't use it in the `write_parquet` then how come it knows where the HDFS is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the document: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/formats.html#parquet-files

you can either use write_table or write_to_dataset function:

**[write_table](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html#pyarrow.parquet.write_table)**

write_table takes multiple parameters, few of those are below:

```
table -> pyarrow.Table
where -> this can be a string or the filesystem object
filesystem -> Default is None
```

Example

```
pq.write_table(table, path, filesystem = fs)
```

or

```
with fs.open(path, 'wb') as f:
    pq.write_table(table, f)
```

**[write_to_dataset](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset.html#pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset)**

You can use write_to_dataset in case you want to partition data based on certain column in the table, Example:

```
pq.write_to_dataset(table, path, filesystem = fs, partition_cols = [col1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```py
with fs.open(path, 'wb') as f:
   pq.write_parquet(table, f)
```

I opened a JIRA about adding some more documentation about this

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6239

Comment: does this work if the file at location path doesn't exist already, right?